# How to show specific parameters based on auth using pundit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, pundit

Say I have a `User` model that has a `username` and a `full_name`.  I want to render a user object using `Active Model Serializer` and only render specific parameters based on if the `current_user` is nil or logged in. Since I'm using `pundit` as well, I was wondering if there was a way to do this using `pundit`.

e.g.

user is `nil`

```
{id:1, username: 'foo'}
```

user is `logged in`

```
{id:1, username: 'foo', full_name: 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just check if `current_user` is `nil` in your `User` serializer. Not sure what version you are on but you can do this with the 0.9 version

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :username, :full_name

  def filter(keys)
    if scope.blank? #current_user is not logged in
      keys - [:full_name]
    else
      keys
    end
  end
end
```